# DocuSign Soap API and baseURL

Tags: docusignapi

We were speaking with one of the DocuSign professional service reps and he mentioned that we need to be using the baseurl retrieved from the Login call for our users with all future requests.  However, I don't see how the baseURL can be used with the SOAP?  It appears that the URLs for each of the calls is hardcoded based on the environment.

Thanks in advance for confirming whether or not the baseURL is required with the SOAP interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign offers a SOAP API as well as a REST API, the DocuSign rep you talked to was talking about the REST API where you use your `baseUrl` for your requests.  You are right that with the SOAP API the URL that you are hitting is the same.  For more information please see the SOAP page inside the DocuSign Developer Center:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center